# Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1,) error in DataSnapshot?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to using Firebase and while I was implementing the credentials for a new user, I noticed that in the debugger Firebase wasn't taking in the information implemented. When I run my app, it would crash and have a:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT error

And I am not sure what is going on. I imported all of the necessary modules. I also tried to make `uid` and `ref` optionals but more errors came out of that. The error appears within the snapshot init with both the `self.ref` and `self.uid`. Here is the  snippet code:

```
struct User {

    var email: String!
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var uid: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var key: String = ""
    var username: String!


    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){

        self.email = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["email"] as? String
        self.firstname = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["firstname"] as! String
        self.lastname = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["lastname"] as! String
        self.uid = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.key = snapshot.key

    }


    init(email: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, uid: String){

        self.email = email
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.uid = uid
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

    }

    func getFullname() -> String{

        return "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
    }


    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any]{
        return ["email":self.email,"firstname":self.firstname,"lastname":self.lastname,"uid":self.uid]
    }

}
```

Firebase passes everything in except for the uid and ref. Here is what it looks like in my debugger:

[image: at 9.40.10 PM.png!]

I want to know why the information is not passing through to the database, basically.

Here Are the places where I placed the User initializer:

func fetchAllUsers(completion: @escaping([User])->Void){

```
    let usersRef = databaseRef.child("users")
    usersRef.observe(.value, with: { (users) in

        var resultArray = [User]()
        for user in users.children {

            let user = User(snapshot: user as! DataSnapshot)
            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!

            if user.uid != currentUser.uid {
                resultArray.append(user)
            }
            completion(resultArray)
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

[image]

Here is the structure of the user's account. The problem is, this does not appear for new accounts that I create.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using `User`'s initializers

Comment: I posted the code where I use the User's initializer.

Comment: Please add the firebase database structure as well

Comment: Are you talking about the content in my UserSerices file?

Comment: I am saying about the data in you see in your firebase console